# MySQL, need some advice about how to setup sitemaps for a site with a lot of pages?

Tags: php, mysql, seo, google-search-console

At the moment I have a sitemap specified in google webmaster tools, which looks like this..

www.mydomain.com/sitemap.php?from=20000&max=10000

This shows 10,000 pages from record id 20,000

I have 80,000 pages and my site maps are slow.

I don't want to end up having lots of sitemaps with these paramaters (as only google knows about them). But the pages pump out too many pages from the database and are really slow.

Can someone advise me what will be both fast and comprehensive and available to all bots ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Set up a cron job which creates static sitemaps.
- Set it to run daily, hourly, or in whatever schedule you like.
- Serve the static files to search engines (no load on database, fast, etc.).
- Use an [index file of sitemaps](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#index)

Comment: What about the setup of the files, I'm going to end up with a lot of sitemap files. Also can I have a sitemap of sitemaps ?

Comment: Yes, you can, see http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.php#index (you can even gzip large files). Added it to the answer